# Capture list item under cursor after mouse wheel scroll animation ends

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I hope this is well received.

I have noticed that the JavaScript `onMouseEnter` event does not trigger when the mouse enters an element as the result of a mouse `wheel` event.

Further, `event.target` of the `wheel` event captures the element the cursor was on *when the event was triggered* (not the one underneath the cursor after the scroll animation).

Is there any way to capture the element underneath the cursor after the scroll animation performed by a mouse wheel is finished?

UPDATE: This only happens in Edge.

A bug report has been opened here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/15836400/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[`onmouseenter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mouseenter)** does indeed trigger when the mouse enters an element as a result of a wheel event, and **[`event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)** does indeed target the event when the animation has finished.

If this is not the case for you, you likely have CSS [**`overflow`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) problems that are causing one of your elements to overlap the element you are trying to target.

All you need to do to target an element after a scroll is to check the `e.target`, as can be seen in the following:

```js
document.getElementById('outer').onmouseover = e => {
  console.clear();
  console.log(e.target);
}
```

```css
#outer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 50px;
  margin: 300px 0 200px 0;
}

#inner {
  background: cyan;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <span id="inner">Mouse over me!</span>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: In Edge, if I hover in the outer div and use the mouse wheel to position the cursor over the inner div, the console still says `<div id="outer">…</div>`. This only works if you don't move the cursor whatsoever during the scroll animation. I am checking to see if this is the case in other browsers.

Comment: Okay so I tried it in Chrome and it works just like you said it would. I wonder if this is a problem with Edge...

Comment: I updated the question to show that the problem only occurs in the Microsoft Edge browser.